# Misinterpretation / Misrepresentation of statistics?

Tags: logic, errors, statistics

I'm looking for a single word or and expression for a faulty use of statistics. It can involve poor **interpretation** or **representation** of statistics or the false assumptions or logic that cause those faults.

A couple of examples:

> - Beaches are dangerous because 95% of shark attacks happen at the beach.
>     (Of course, because most humans don't spend much time in mid-ocean!)
> - Statistically, you're most likely to die within 5 miles of your house, so that is the most dangerous place to be.
>     (Of course, because most people spend most of their time close to home!)
> - The majority of the earth's waste comes from Asia, thus, Asians are wasteful.
>     (Not really, Asian people make up 60% of the earth's population!)

I'm looking for a term or expression to describe this poor use of statistics.

Comment: Look up logical fallacies and you'll find what you need.

Comment: @Brendan Charles You need to clarify whether for you "poorly presented statistics" means __badly designed statistics__ or __well-designed but badly presented/analyzed statistics__ .

Comment: The word you are seeking is "bullshit", but I imagine you are shooting for a higher register. I don't think there is a need for a shorter way of saying misinterpretation of statistics or logical fallacy, because "bullshit" is always available when a curt characterization is needed. Thus a curt, high register term is uneconomical and most likely does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can apply one word in this case.

Misinterpretation **is not** malicious in any way. It is a lack of understanding or unwittingly coming to the wrong conclusion by using data badly.

Misrepresentation, on the other hand, **is** malicious. There is an intent to deceive and control a situation through half truths and outright falsehoods.

I cannot see how you can combine these two terms under one heading

Answer (score 2):

> - Beaches are dangerous because 95% of shark attacks happen at the beach.
>   (Of course, because humans usually don't spend their time in
>   mid-ocean)
> - Statistically, you're most likely to die within 5 miles of your house, so that is the most dangerous place to be.
>   (Of course, because that where most people spend most of their time)
> - The majority of the earth's waste comes from Asia, thus, Asians are wasteful.
>   (Not really, more because Asia makes up 60% of the earth's
>   population)

The parenthetical statements above have **exposed** three *[faulty generalizations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulty_generalization)*:

> reach a conclusion from weak premises. Unlike fallacies of relevance,
> in fallacies of defective induction, **the premises are related to the
> conclusions** yet only **weakly buttress the conclusions**. A faulty
> generalization is thus produced.
>
> *Wikipedia.org*
> **Emphasis** mine

- The fact that *95% of shark attacks happen at the beach*, is
  **related** to the conclusion, but does **not** support the conclusion directly.
- The fact that *you're most likely to die within 5 miles of your
  house*, is **related** to the conclusion, but does **not** support
  the conclusion directly.
- The fact that *the majority of the earth's waste comes from Asia*, is **related** to the conclusion, but does **not** support
  the conclusion directly.

---

This use of statistics can also be labeled as ***defective induction*** or an *[inductive fallacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulty_generalization#Inductive_fallacies)*:

> happens when a conclusion is made of premises that lightly support it.
> *Wikipedia.org*

Accurate statistics are often used to *[induce](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/induce)* a conclusion that does not actually follow logically.

---

Both of the terms suggested above are found on the *[List of fallacies at Wikipedia.org](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fallacies#Faulty_generalizations)*.

Answer (score 1):

There are **logical fallacies** implicit in the examples that you cite.  Logical fallacies don't necessarily rely on use of numbers but they are the true issue with your examples.

Nevertheless, the phenomenon of deliberately misrepresenting statistics has been called **lying with numbers**.

There is a well known quote, with popular, but apocryphal attribution to Benjamin Disraeli and/or Mark Twain, that:

> There are three kinds of lies: Lies, Damned Lies, and *Statistics*.

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lies,_damned_lies,_and_statistics).

Answer (score 0):

This is the **Texas Sharpshooter Fallacy**.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_sharpshooter_fallacy):

> The Texas sharpshooter fallacy is an informal fallacy which is
>   committed when differences in data are ignored, but similarities are
>   stressed. From this reasoning a false conclusion is inferred....
>
> The name comes from a joke about a Texan who fires some gunshots at
>   the side of a barn, then paints a target centered on the biggest
>   cluster of hits and claims to be a sharpshooter.

Essentially, an unrepresentative / unstratified sample of a population is chosen, and a false conclusion arrived at (whether by design or through incompetence).

Answer (score 0):

I found some good phrases in wikipedia's article on "misuse of statistics," and a book called *Sense and Nonsense of Statistical Inference: Controversy: Misuse, and Subtlety*, which I found by googling my first idea, *lousy statistics.*

Here are a few possibilities: cherry picking, bad statistics, nonsense disguised as "statistics," sensationalism disguised as statistics.

When someone misuses statistics to reach an appalling conclusion, maybe we could say *reactionary statistics* (or racist or fascist).

Empiricist.

Pseudo-statistics.

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps:

[**"skewed statistics"**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22poorly%20presented%20statistics%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22skewed%20statistics%22) About 914 results

Also: **predisposed, distorted, slanted. biased, prejudiced, partial, partisan, one-sided, bigoted, discriminatory, distorted, warped, twisted, skewed**

> **skew**
>
> transitive verb  :  to give a bias or disproportionate weight to : 
>   **distort**
>
> *the list is badly skewed in favor of the subjects with which I myself feel most at home — Bonaro W. Overstreet*
>
> Merriam-Webster Unabridged Dictionary

E.g.,

> The Downsizing of America - Page 113 Ronald Ayling - 1997
>
> The reason that this is so is that a decision based on **faulty or
>   skewed statistics** is not based on fact but some skewed perception of
>   fact.

Comment: Has a technical meaning, so is perhaps not ideal: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness

Comment: I don't think that   skewed statistics  are  necessarily faulty: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness

Comment: Or we're looking for a single term that both describes it relates to statistics and that the statistics are false.

Comment: @Josh61 Of course not.

Comment: @Croad Langshan I'll argue that when 900 experts are using it in their books, it must be pretty well established.

Comment: Somewhat well established perhaps, but I'd say clearly less confusing than "faulty statistics".  Also, why say "experts"?  Every native speaker -- not only subject experts who write books -- is an expert *in English* (and "faulty statistics" gets 3 times as many hits), and these authors are largely not experts in statistics.  Finally, I guess you did not check each of the 900 to see *how* they are using that word.

Comment: @MariusHancu - But if 800 of those 900 uses are to the effect of "this is not an example of 'skewed statistics'", what it that an example of?